# Visual Studio Setup Project, prevent overwrite of additional files

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer, installation, project

I have an xml file that i copy to some folder...
C:\ProgramData*\XML_Project_Data.xml
With project setup in vs2017, .net 4.6
The install app works fine however I can't find any settings to prevent overwriting the XML_Project_Data.xml if this file already exists. I want this condition as I only want to send the xml file to the install location when it isn't already there.
cheers,
Fabs

Comment: Are you using a Visual Studio installer project or WiX? It is not 100% clear. What kind of application is this? Will the XML file be modified during application operation (read / write) - or is it a read-only settings file - perhaps tweaked outside the application using a text editor? Please be specific.

Comment: Hi TY, I am using visual studio installer project, it's a class library that runs as an addin in a cad design software that invokes it's start. the xml is a read only settings file.